# How do I add variables within string in python?

Tags: python, string, variables, curl, web-scraping

I am writing a python code to scrape website data through cURL. I converted cURL into python code using https://curlconverter.com/ . The code works just fine but I want to customize according to my need like in this line of code

`data = '{"appDate":{"startDate":"2022-01-05T18:30:00.000Z","endDate":"2022-01-06T18:30:00.000Z"},"page_number":1,"page_size":20,"sort":{"key":"AppointmentStartTime","order":-1}}'`

After "startDate" I want to add my variable (startdate) which I created like this

[variable code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6sZl.png)

I tried to add variables like this
`data = '{"appDate":{"startDate":'+ startdate +,"endDate":'+ enddate +'},"page_number":1,"page_size":20,"sort":{"key":"AppointmentStartTime","order":-1}}'` but this did not work.

Also adding '+ str(startdate) +' did not help.

Please can anyone tell me how this should be done.

Comment: By using a JSON library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to transform the json data string into a dictionary using the [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). Then you can freely manipulate and export your data.

```
import json

raw_data = '{"appDate":{"startDate":"2022-01-05T18:30:00.000Z","endDate":"2022-01-06T18:30:00.000Z"},"page_number":1,"page_size":20,"sort":{"key":"AppointmentStartTime","order":-1}}'
data = json.loads(raw_data) # load json from string to dict
data['appDate']['startDate'] = 23
data['appDate']['endDate'] = 42
print(json.dumps(data)) # export dict to json string
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @AnimeshPandey Glad to hear. You might also want to read-up on [python's string interpolation features](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-interpolation/) if you need to work with raw strings in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

In the example you have shown, there is probably only a small mistake right after `+ startdate +`, with the apostrophe. Compare carefully:

Your code (with the mistake):

```
    data = '{"appDate":{"startDate":'+ startdate +,"endDate":'+ enddate +'},"page_number":1,"page_size":20,"sort":{"key":"AppointmentStartTime","order":-1}}'
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Fixed code:

```
data = '{"appDate":{"startDate":'+ startdate +',"endDate":'+ enddate +'},"page_number":1,"page_size":20,"sort":{"key":"AppointmentStartTime","order":-1}}'
```